# Regular Expression From MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a table in MySQL that contains couple of expressions that I want to pass to `preg_replace`

My code:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
while($r=mysql_query($q)) {
  $expressions = $r['expressions'];
}
$expressions = explode("\n", $expressions);
foreach ($expressions as $expression) {
  $content = preg_replace($expression, '', $content);
}
```

Some data in database:

```
#<div class="FBTbtn">(.*?)</div>#
#<!-- Extra Link -->(.*?)<!-- End Of Extra Link -->#
#<a(.*?)/a>#
#Learn More:#
```

Comment: is each line one db entry or the whole bloock is?

Comment: The whole block is. I do explode then foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the it by using "," instead of "\n"

Code:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
while($r=mysql_query($q)) {
  //Remove last "," from string
  $expressions = rtrim($r['expressions'], ",");
}
//Explode string into array based on "," instead of "\n"
$expressions = explode(",", $expressions);
foreach ($expressions as $expression) {
  $content = preg_replace($expression, '', $content);
}
```

Data in database should look like:

```
#<div class="FBTbtn">(.*?)</div>#,#<!-- Extra Link -->(.*?)<!-- End Of Extra Link -->#,#<a(.*?)/a>#,#Learn More:#,
```

Answer (score 0):

As described on the mysql_query() function page, iterate through the results with mysql_fetch_assoc(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

```
$content = 'foo bar baz';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM expressions");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $content = preg_replace($row['expression'], '', $content);
}
```

By the way, mysql_*() functions are deprecated. You should switch to PDO.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: What's the error ? What have you tried ? Have you simply done a copy/past on the code in the answer ?

Comment: [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier ' '
This error displays if the expression in contains HTML tags

Comment: This error can be easily resolved!! so why not you please answer me how to resolve it? If I found a resolve for this in Google I won't post a question in here

Comment: You're just showing a lack of research. I would be pleased to help you if you tried just a little bit.

Comment: @MohamedAtef This site likes you to show you spent at least 5 min figuring it out or trying, versus saying it has an error fix it.